# What's the option "blocks" in SonataPageBundle container configuration?

Tags: symfony, sonata

I can't find any documentation about the `blocks` option in [SonataPageBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/page_composer.html). An example template:

```
   2columns:
       path: 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle::demo_2columns_layout.html.twig'
       name: '2 columns layout'
       inherits_containers: default
       containers:
           left_col:
               name: Left column
               blocks:
                   - sonata.media.block.media
                   - sonata.media.block.gallery
                   - sonata.media.block.feature_media
           right_col:
               name: Right column
               blocks:
                   - sonata.news.block.recent_posts
                   - sonata.order.block.recent_orders
                   - sonata.product.block.recent_products
```

What's the purpose of the blocks i.e. `sonata.media.block.media` defined in the left column container?

Answer (score 1):

These are [default blocks](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/blob/3.x/Model/Template.php#L116) that should always be present in this containers if you use this template.

Comment: Ok, how should i test it? I mean, looking at the page composer i can't see those blocks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug… One good first step might be to debug the line I linked to, to see if it is called, and if yes, if the options you specify do appear at this line.